# Rails 4 Multiple ActiveRecord Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table ProductOrder that has multiple foreign keys which link to a SecurityUser table.
I'm trying to figure out a way to configure my model so that I can load up multiple SecurityUser foreign keys when I return a ProductOrder from a query.

Here is a section of my product_order.rb:

```
class ProductOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'product_order'

    belongs_to :security_user, :class_name => 'SecurityUser', :foreign_key => :ordered_by_client_user
    belongs_to :security_user, :class_name => 'SecurityUser', :foreign_key => :staff_engager1
    belongs_to :security_user, :class_name => 'SecurityUser', :foreign_key => :staff_engager2
    belongs_to :security_user, :class_name => 'SecurityUser', :foreign_key => :last_updated_by_user
```

Here is the corresponding section of security_user.rb:

```
class SecurityUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'security_user'

    has_many :product_orders, :class_name => 'ProductOrder'
```

These models were generated using a gem designed to create models from a DB schema.

So what I would like to be able to do is load a ProductOrder from an ActiveRecord query and from that result I could access information from some of the SecurityUser objects, such as  ordered_by_client_user or staff_engager1.

I'm re-writing an application from Java to RoR, so I previously used Hibernate and JPA query and I was used to having all of the objects load up with the query. I've tried the following with the same result every time:

```
ProductOrder.includes(:security_user)
ProductOrder.joins(:security_user)
ProductOrder.eager_load(:security_user)
ProductOrder.preload(:security_user)
```

But the problem is that RoR doesn't know which foreign key to load. I'd like to avoid having to make "get" methods on the model just to access these foreign keys, but if that's what it takes then so be it. My current workaround is just building dynamic, messy .joins() statements.

Any suggestions or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be using same name as `security_user` for all.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes sense. Since I'm already defining the corresponding table in the :class_name section. Just tested it on one field and it seems to work. Like I said, I used a gem to generate the models so I wasn't sure if they were 100% accurate. Please post your response as an answer and I will give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using same name i.e, **`security_user`** in your **`ProductOrder`** model for all the **`associations`**.So it probably won't work.

You should change those names(1.e, `security_user`) to some meaningful and different names to get it worked.